# What should I use to use ICQ with Python?

Tags: python, icq

I want to write a script to support my clients online. I decided to use ICQ-protocol for this (kind a icq-bot).
I have 25 icq uins. I need something that will be able to:

1. Make them all online
2. If some uins got disconnected - reconnect them.
3. Use proxy to login, because ICQ server could not accept connection from one IP.
4. Receive some messages and answer on them.

What should I use to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: ... I didn't even know ICQ was still around...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) (a.k.a. Jabber) instead of ICQ, really.

It's a free protocoll, and there are python APIs for it, like [jabber.py](http://jabberpy.sourceforge.net/) and [xmpppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/).

xmpppy is as easy as:

```
jid = xmpp.protocol.JID('your id')
cl = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(),debug=[])
cl.connect()
cl.auth(jid.getNode(), 'your password')
cl.send(xmpp.protocol.Message('reciever id', 'your text'))
```

---

Also, you can use so called transports to use XMPP to transparently send/reviece messages from other protocols like ICQ, MSN, AOL etc, which may be what you need if you *really* need ICQ.

---

Otherwise, I only know about [NanoICQ](http://wiki.wxpython.org/NanoICQ), which claims to be a python based ICQ client, I don't know if the project is still active...

Comment: I like jabber, but icq is more popular in my country, unfortunately.

Comment: @Alex That's not a big problem. Just find a jabber server that offers ICQ transport (like jabme.de for example), and you can connect ICQ accounts to your jabber account. This is what I do, and it work's perfectly.

Comment: @Alex I must agree, use Jabber. And do note that you can, as stated, "use ICQ through Jabber".

Comment: Is it possible to transport 20-30 icq uins at time? I should support groups of client. Each group should know 5 uins.